SQLAlchemy defer.raiseload parameter not working
As you can see in the documentation, raiseload=True, should raise an exception, but it doesn't, at least for me. Any solution?
The following example prints the address but it shouldn't because of setting raiseload to True.
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    firstname: Mapped[str]
    lastname: Mapped[str]
    address: Mapped[str]


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    data = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        user = User(
            user_id=i,
            firstname=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=16)),
            lastname=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=16)),
            address=''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=32)),
        )
        data.append(user)
    session.add_all(data)
    session.commit()

    user = session.scalar(select(User).options(defer(User.address, raiseload=True)))
    print(user.address)


The behaviour in the question seems to occur when an object is loaded or added into a session, then expired (either explicitly or implicitly through .commit()), and then loaded once more with the defer loader option and raiseload=True.
# Assume a row already exists in the database.

with orm.Session(engine) as s:
    user = s.get(User, 1)
    s.expire(user)
    user = s.scalar(select(User).options(defer(User.address, raiseload=True))
    user.address # <- no error

Expunging the object from the session prior to loading will result in the expected behaviour.
with orm.Session(engine) as s:
    user = s.get(User, 1)
    s.expunge(user)
    user = s.scalar(select(User).options(defer(User.address, raiseload=True))
    user.address # <- error

The expected behaviour will also occur if the object is not loaded prior to the deferred load.
with orm.Session(engine) as s:
    user = s.scalar(select(User).options(defer(User.address, raiseload=True))
    user.address # <- error


If you want an explanation as to wny the behaviour is like this, you will probably need to open a discussion on GitHub.
